# Explicit formula for the equalizer of coalgebras

Tags: category-theory, hopf-algebras, coalgebras, graded-algebras, differential-graded-algebras

The article [*Limits of Coalgebras, Bialgebras and Hopf Algebras*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.0318) offers two descriptions for the equalizer of two unital coassociative coalgebras over a field. The latter description (Remark 1.2) is explicit and claims that, given $f,g:C\rightarrow D$ two morphisms of coalgebras, the equalizer $(E,i)$ is given by

$$E=\lbrace{ c\in C/ c_{(1)}\otimes f(c_{(2)})\otimes c_{(3)}=c_{(1)}\otimes g(c_{(2)})\otimes c_{(3)}}\rbrace$$

and $i:E\rightarrow C$ the inclusion.

I understand this is indeed the equalizer when $E,D$ are Hopf algebras, by using the antipode. However, I cannot conclude the same for coalgebras. Any suggestion?, please. Is there a similar description for dg coalgebras?.
Thanks.

Comment: Your $E$ can be equivalently described as $\ker\left(\left(\operatorname{id}_C \otimes \left(f-g\right) \otimes \operatorname{id}_C\right) \circ \Delta^{\left(2\right)}\right)$, where $\Delta^{\left(2\right)} : C \to C \otimes C \otimes C$ is the map sending each $c \in C$ to $c_{\left(1\right)} \otimes c_{\left(2\right)} \otimes c_{\left(3\right)}$. Thus, your claim about coalgebras is a particular case of Exercise 1.4.30 in [Darij Grinberg, Victor Reiner, *Hopf Algebras in Combinatorics*, arXiv:1409.8356v5](https://arxiv.org/src/1409.8356v5/anc/HopfComb-v73-with-solutions.pdf) (applied ...

Comment: ... to $D$ and $f-g$ instead of $U$ and $f$). That $f-g$ is not a coalgebra homomorphism doesn't matter; nor do $f$ and $g$ have to be. Now, what about dg-coalgebras? I don't know, but as a newbie I wouldn't mind a definition of the notion you are using (something is telling me there is more than one).

Comment: @darij Thank you for the reference.

Comment: @darji I got impressed, there are several useful exercises solved there.